# Append a string from specific number

Tags: c, string

```
strncpy(string1, string2, 18);
strcat(string1, "Statement cache has been cleared.");
```

Any way I can merge this into one function call?

Regards,
Vivek

Answer (score 1):

May be you like this using `strcpy(s1 + pos, s2)` instead of `strcat()`, see example below:

code:

```
@:~$ cat x.c

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
 char s1[10] = "0123456";
 char s2[10] = "abcde";
 int pos = 3;

 strcpy(s1 + pos, s2);
 printf("\n %s\n", s1);
 return 0;
}
```

run:

```
~$ ./a.out 

 012abcde
```

I am not handling buffer-overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
sprintf(string1,"%18s%s",string2,"Statement cache has been cleared.");
```

or

```
snprintf(string1,<Size>,"%18s%s",string2,"Statement cache has been cleared.");
```

Comment: Better yet, `snprintf()`.